# Git submodules: Can we make each branch of the main project track the same branch in the submodules?

Tags: git

I read some info about submodules, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189575/git-submodule-tracking-latest), [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/GitSubmodules/article.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40219209/does-git-submodule-branch-switch-along-with-main-projects-branch) .

My question that remains is: Can I simply track my submodule's master branch in my main project's master branch and my submodule's production branch in my main project's production branch?  Is there an easy way to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). Before/After certain `git` actions, git can run scripts and take action.  The hook you are probably most interested in is the `post-checkout` hook.

Basically, within your repository is a `.git/hooks` directory.  If you have executable permissions on a file and the file exactly matches the name of an event (ie: *no* `.sample`), then `git` will execute the script at the proper time.

```
vim .git/hooks/post-checkout
chmod +x .git/hooks/post-checkout
```

Using this information you could create a bash script that checks out each of your submodules after checking out a branch in the main repository:

```
#!/bin/bash
CURRENT_GIT_BRANCH="`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`"
cd modules/module001
git checkout ${CURRENT_GIT_BRANCH}
cd ../../
cd modules/module002
git checkout ${CURRENT_GIT_BRANCH}
```

You could even get fancy and use a list of modules by looking at the directory structure, or the `.gitmodules` file of your repository.

This means that when you perform `git checkout BRANCH` in your main repository, the same branch will be checked out for each submodule listed and described in the `post-checkout` hook.

It should be noted that you cannot commit the hooks to your repository directly, as that could pose security risk when cloning new repositories, etc.